identify three same color consecutive candle where 1st candle's volume>2nd candle's volume and 3rd candle's volume>1st candle's volume in tradingview
identify three same color consecutive candle where 1st candle's volume>2nd candle's volume and 3rd candle's volume>1st candle's volume in tradingview in any selected time frame of an asset.
Required pine script for that purpose in trading view
